# Bind arrayList in ROOM database observeForever() or observe() method

Tags: android, arraylist, observable, android-room

How we can bind `arrayList` in ROOM database `observeForever()` or `observe()` method

```
 notificationModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        NotificationRepository notificationRepository = new NotificationRepository(getApplicationContext());
        notificationRepository.getAllNotification().observe(NotificationActivity.this,new Observer<List<Notification>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Notification> notifications) {
                for (org.jembi.careconekta.dbTables.Notification notification : notifications) {
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");
                    System.out.println(notification.getTitle());
                    System.out.println(notification.getMessage());
                    NotificationModel notificationModel = new NotificationModel();
                    notificationModel.setNotificationMsg(notification.getMessage());
                    notificationModelArrayList.add(notificationModel);
                }
            }
        });
```

---

`System.out.println` works fine but `notificationModel` is not added in `notificationModelArrayList`

Comment: Please describe or show the error it displays

Comment: @AbdurRahman There is no any error in code but `notificationModelArrayList.size()` returns 0

Comment: add debug at last line of array list add method and check "notificationModel" have data or not.